# Prevent TypeORM from generating constraints

Tags: javascript, orm, nestjs, typeorm, history-tables

I am extending a class Entity to create a **history table**. The history table, must not inherit the unique constraints from the base class because we need to duplicate most of the data in there. Of course, I can just copy the properties without extending the base class but will result in maintaining two classes for each history table.

*There is any way, to prevent TypeORM from generating constraints for a class entity?*

I am thinking about something similar to [avoiding foreign key constraint creation](https://typeorm.io/#/relations-faq/avoid-foreign-key-constraint-creation). Maybe a class decorator (something like `@IgnoreConstraints`) would be nice to have for this type of situations.

```
//Base class with required constraint
@Entity()
@Unique(['email', 'shopId'])
export class Customer {}

// Will inherit the unique constraint 
@Entity()
export class CustomerHistory extends Customer {}
```

More, I am using anchan828's very useful [TypeORM History](https://github.com/anchan828/typeorm-helpers/tree/master/packages/history#readme) library which is adding a `dropUniqueIndices` method to be used in a later migration but unfortunately will later result in auto-generated migrations including those constraints and `schema:sync` will no longer work.

Thanks!

Comment: you can create a `parent` class (ex. `CustomerBase`) with all the common fields and logic, also without the `@Entity` decorator. With this new class, you create the `Customer` and `CustomerHistory` entity classes which extends from the previously created class

Comment: @Motakjuq this is a valid point and can be useful, thanks, but I am also looking forward to a database/ORM level solution